# How to store this type of values in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have following requirements

```
class a:
   _name='a'
   _columns={
         'store'=fields.one2many('b','link1','History'),
       }
class b:
   _name='b'
   _columns={
           'name'=fields.char('Employee Names'),
           'age'=fields.char('Age'),
           'link1': fields.many2one('a','Link'),
   }
```

This module has one2many field which has two fields **'name','age'** .This values stored by below module

```
class y:
   _name='y'
   _columns={
        'detail': fields.one2many('z','link','Details'),
     }

class z:
    _name='z'
    _columns={
          'name1': fields.char('Name'),
          'age2': fields.char('Age'),
          'link': fields.many2one('y','Link'),
       }
```

In this module i will store few names and age . And I wanted a button in this module which has function to store this value to **'a'**  module .Data has to append like keeping track of history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the value to `a` model you have to `create` them.

```
def track(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
  values = []
  for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
     for line in obj.detail:
        values.append([0, 0, {'name': line.name1,
                              'age':line.age2,                                                
                              'link1': line.link.id}
                      ])
     self.pool.get('a').create(cr, uid, {'store': values})
```